# Concatenate multiple rows in MS Access 2013

Tags: vba, ms-access, concatenation

I am from Bangladesh & making a database for my office using MS Access 2013. Here I have the following tables.

tblPerson

| PersonID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| P-1 | Robert |
| P-2 | John |

tblPlot

| PlotID | PersonID | Plots |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | P-1 | 101 |
| 2 | P-1 | 102 |
| 3 | P-2 | 103 |
| 4 | P-2 | 104 |
| 5 | P-2 | 105 |

I want concatenate the rows as below.

tblReport

| PersonID | Plots |
| --- | --- |
| P-1 | 101, 102 |
| P-2 | 103, 104, 105 |

I have read a few process but havn't understand anything. If anyone can describe me the process easily, It will be a life saver for me.

I have read the AllenBrowne function & all the related answers in this website. I am new to Access, so I don't know how & where to put the codes.

I copied the DJoin Function Module & saved as Module1 in VBA. Then I tried the SQL Query with

```
SELECT Table2.PID,
Djoin("[Plot]","[Table2","[PID] = " & [PID] & "", ": ") AS Plots
FROM Table2
GROUP BY Table2.PID, Djoin("[Plot] = " & [PID] & "", ": ")
ORDER BY Table2.PID;
```

but, it is showing the following:

[image]

What I am missing?